# tensorflow keras mask in transformer tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Looks like the use of mask in this transformer tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer is inconsistent with how mask is used in keras normally.

There it create the mask this way: "The mask indicates where pad value 0 is present: it outputs a 1 at those locations, and a 0 otherwise." i.e., mask = 1 when value = 0.

In this keras doc about mask https://keras.io/guides/understanding_masking_and_padding/, it says:  "each individual False entry indicates that the corresponding timestep should be ignored during processing."  i.e., mask = 0 when value = 0. This is opposite what the transformer tutorial says.

I would like to confirm that the transformer tutorial works.

My understanding is:

1. by default, mask_zero=False when creating tf.keras.layers.Embedding so Embedding layer doesn't create a mask by itself.
2. the mask created explicitly in transformer tutorial is passed down to layers such as MultiHeadAttention which understand the way mask is created.

So transformer tutorial works. Am I right?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, masks created in transformers are called `attention_mask` & are used for making predictions. Attention masks in transformers are task specific as well. Also, they vary based on the type of transformer model used.